# Opposite of bringSubviewToFront?

Tags: iphone, uiview, subview

As well as wanting a view to be on top of everything, you might want a view to be below everything, but there is no bringSubviewToBack:. Why not and how do I bring a subview to back?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`sendSubviewToBack`?

Comment: I love Apple's consistent naming! :) Thank you!

Comment: It is certainly consistent.  Of course, it works best if you're a native English speaker, immediately realizing "send" should be the opposite of "bring"...